# AbgularJS drop down hold the selected value after screen refresh

Tags: angularjs

I'm Developing requirement for an application using angularJS which is an existing application.

Its a search screen where we have 3 drop down box.
Everything works fine in search screen based on search.I'm displaying data in grid when the user clicks on any record in grid it goes to the 
new screen which show details information on it.

When i use the browser back button. The initial value what was selected earlier  in drop down is refreshed.

I understand that screen is loading again so all the values selected will be reset.
But i need to display the selected values to user again how can i get that done?

I am storing  all the selected values back in local Storage so that i can use those values to filled up when the browser back button is clicked.

```
  <span ng-hide="asyncLoadCount > 0">
        <select name="UserPicker"
                id="userPicker"
                class="form-control"
                ng-change="userPicker()"
                ng-model="user.FriendlyName "
                ng-options="User as users.FriendlyName for User in itemsSource() track by User.RoleId"
                ng-disabled="isDisabled()"
                fix-ie-select="itemsSource()">
            <option value="" class="placeholder">Select a User from the list</option>
        </select>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store selected values to local storage, you need to get them again and select them in select boxes.